# Working with UserIds and ProfileIds

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application, a User can have One Profile.

The user creates a account by entering an email and a password. This information are then stored in a Users-table.

After the user has created an account, they can then create a profile: Elf-profile, Dwarf-profile and a Human-profile that going to belong to the user.

Here is my ProfileModel:

```
   public class Profile : IProfile
    {
        public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string ElfName{ get; set; }
        public string DwarfName{ get; set; }
        public string HumanName{ get; set; }
    }
```

My question is: How should I handle/work ProfileId throughout the application? If I just had the user, I could call `User.Identity.GetUserId()` everytime I need to get the Id of the user.

But how about ProfileId? Should I use the UserId everytime to get the ProfileId? Should I use a HiddenFor for the ProfileId everytime I want to work with a profile?

Is there any best practices to follow here? Any suggestions from you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most of the stored info I get the `userID` and then use something like `var profile = DbContext.Profiles.Single(profile => profile.UserId == userID)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the relation between User and UserProfile one to one then you should refactor your UserProfile so that Profile.UserId is Primary key and Forign key on the User table

```
public class Profile : IProfile
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string ElfName{ get; set; }
        public string DwarfName{ get; set; }
        public string HumanName{ get; set; }
    }
```